# Accidentally deleted or lost the .xctest file in xcode 5 for my iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, xcode5.1, xctest

I was trying to change my app's name earlier and for whatever reason what I normally do didn't work and so now things are sort of screwed up. I ended up manually changing the app name in various places in xcode and now the name appears to have successfully changed.

The app currently cleans, builds, and runs fine for both the simulator and my physical iPhone.

However, one thing that is bothering me is that if I go to the Project Navigator, and scroll down and view the contents of the Products folder, my `.xctest` file is red. If I select it, and then view it's details in the File Inspector on the right, and click the arrow button to view it in the finder, it doesn't take me anywhere.

If I open the folder that it's supposed to be in with Finder, it currently has 4 files. 2 of the files are `.app` files, one has the old app name and the other has the new app name. Both of these show warning icons like this in the Finder: [image]

The other 2 files are `dSYM` files. One uses the old app name, and the other uses the new app name.

Like I said the app currently cleans, builds, and runs fine for both the simulator and my physical iPhone, but it still bothers me that I have somehow lost or deleted the `.xctest` file.

I am about to submit this app as my first app to the app store and I want to make sure that everything is perfect.

Do I need to create a new `.xctest` file from scratch?

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: .xctest is real vent to unit testing when you want to test the app to make sure everything works the way it should. It won't matter if it's not part of your binary when you upload the app. So go ahead and submit your app. You should be fine. Here is the complete doc's on the unit testing just for your reference. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UnitTestYourApp/UnitTestYourApp.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I went back and unzipped an older version of my app from 2 months ago and ran that, and realized that it is also missing the .xctest file so it looks like I never had it setup properly to begin with. I'll have to spend some time learning more about unit testing.

Comment: I went through the same thing when I first started. Glad to be of help my friend.